# Wordpress child theme styles not overriding previously enqueued styles

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm new to WordPress dev and trying to build a simple child theme. I'm going **crazy** trying to get the child styles to override the bootstrap styles enqueued by the parent theme.

Everything I've seen online says that to solve this problem, you have to make sure that your child theme is enqueued last, and I believe I've achieved that in my child's functions.php:

```
<?php

    // enqueue styles
    function sparkling_enqueue_styles() {

        // enqueue parent styles
        wp_enqueue_style('sparkling-theme', get_template_directory_uri() .'/style.css');

        // enqueue child styles
        wp_enqueue_style('child-theme', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/style.css', array('sparkling-theme', 'sparkling-bootstrap'), '1.0', true);
    }

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sparkling_enqueue_styles');
```

This gives me a head section with the following order of elements when inspected in dev tools:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="sparkling-theme-css" 
href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/sparkling/style.css?
ver=4.8" type="text/css" media="all">

<link rel="stylesheet" id="sparkling-bootstrap-css" 
href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-
content/themes/sparkling/inc/css/bootstrap.min.css?ver=4.8" type="text/css" 
media="all">

<link rel="stylesheet" id="child-theme-css" 
href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/sparkling-
child/style.css?ver=1.0" type="text/css" media="1">

<link rel="stylesheet" id="sparkling-style-css" 
href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/sparkling-
child/style.css?ver=4.8" type="text/css" media="all">
```

I've added this bit of CSS into my child theme stylesheet:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: right !important;
    }
}
```

But when I go to inspect my .navbar-header element, it's still floating to the left, thanks to bootstrap styles:

```
bootstrap.min.css?ver=4.8:5

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: left;
}
```

I have two questions. I don't know if they're related.

1. **Why is my child theme styling not overriding the bootstrap styles?**
2. Where is that final stylesheet (sparkling-style-css) in the head coming from? I think it's the shadow of a previous attempt at enqueuing, long since deleted from my functions.php file.

Any help is very much appreciated! I've tried dequeuing re-enqueuing the bootstrap file, but that doesn't seem to help and it jacks up other parts of the design.

Comment: Could you post your header.php file code as well and a live link to the website if possible?

Comment: About the second stylesheet, I think it's because WordPress automatically includes that style.css with the `sparkling-style` name. You use `child-theme` so it doesn't overwrite it. Try to enqueue it as `sparkling-style` and it should be ok.

Comment: Hey @pomaaa, I just updated the question because I discovered my error. Thanks for reaching out.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of research and poking through my enqueuing code and PHP, it turns out that there was a problem with the child stylesheet that I was trying to enqueue: a closing bracket had been deleted somewhere deep in my CSS, and it was either keeping the file from being enqueued, or keeping the styles from applying.

I'm still not sure why the last (nonexistent) stylesheet was appearing in the header, but it was resistant to being dequeued, so I applied the following code recommended by someone else on SO:

```
// dequeue ghost duplicate child styles
function remove_assets() {
    wp_dequeue_style('sparkling-style');
    wp_deregister_style('sparkling-style'); 
}

add_action('wp_print_styles', 'remove_assets', 99999);
```

I don't know if this is the most elegant way to dequeue a stubborn asset, but it seems to work.